# How to bind grid in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I cant bind my Grid. I dont know what I am doing wrong, the grid appears empty when I run the program.

here is my code ::

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            this.BindGrid(this.GridView1);


    }
    private void BindGrid(GridView grid)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Person", cn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        grid.DataSource = dt;
        grid.DataBind();
    }


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="margin-left: 240px">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
            GridLines="None" Width="856px" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" 
            ShowFooter = "true" ShowHeader="true" BorderStyle="Groove" CaptionAlign="Top" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Home Phone #" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cell #" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Email Address" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="NIC #" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
         />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
</asp:GridView>
</div>

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Do you get an error?  Is the screen blank?

Comment: Is your `Page_Load` event actually wired up?.. does any code execute?

Comment: please be more descriptive of the problem providing necessary error details or your observations.

Comment: i dont get any error @mellamokb .. the grid appears empty.. and there is some data present in the Database

Comment: yes.. @Quintin .. the code also executes.. as i have previously sayd.. there is not any error in the code.. but the the appears empty..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you aren't hooking up to the databinding in your Bound fields example:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="ID" headertext="ID"/>
```

you can find a full example of how to set up a databound field on msdn:[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.aspx)

Comment: when i added datafield = "ID" , the ID`s appeard only in the grid but not the data.. :s

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void BindGrid(GridView grid)
{
  using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Some Connection string"))
  using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Person", cn))
  {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        grid.DataSource = dt;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: . sorry mate! this is also doing the same.. I can not see any of my data in the grid! :)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you do not want to use bound field, then delete the following

**AutoGenerateColumns = "false"**

Comment: This is a suggestion. Should be part of comment section.